# How to output view content as grid in custom template?

Tags: views, theming

I have **created a view** for content type xyz with **fields** F1, F2,F3,F4.

I open the group "**advanced**", clicked on "**Theme: Information**".

There are couple of template files, that are used by view.

**I chosen the desired template and copy it into to the template folder**.

Now, from views module, in theme folder, I opened `views-view-grid.tpl.php` and copy the content of this file to the file I have created in my template folder.

**But output is not coming in grid format.**

**Is there any way to customize the fields of view in html structure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[what if I want to use html and php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188892/how-to-output-view-content-as-grid-in-custom-template/188902#comment-229020)**

Ok, now that I remember there is another method.

Add the following code to the bottom of your **template.php** file (located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/` folder)

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

      if ($vars['view']->name == "view_name" && $vars['view']->current_display == "block_1"){
        $vars['fields']['title']->content = // do php or whatever you want to it here
      }
    }
```

- replace **themename** with your theme name
- replace **view_name** with your view name
- replace **block_1** with your [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

To add html, Ex:

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  if ($vars['view']->name == "view_name" && $vars['view']->current_display == "block_1"){
  $a = $vars['fields']['title']->content;
  $vars['fields']['title']->content = "<div class='others'>" . $a . "</div>";
  }
}
```

**With this method your grid should remain intact.**

[image]

Comment: @SugandhKhanna you're welcome, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to customize the fields of view in html structure?

There are various methods to add html to your fields.

One of them if you just want to [add divs to your fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188800/how-to-generate-custom-template-for-views-page#answer-188853)

Another would be to REWRITE RESULTS. You need to use the replacement pattern.

ex: `<div class="cool"><b>[field_example]</b></div>`

[image]

**Note:** If you have more fields, they are not showing because they are below the body. If you want to show in the replacement patterns, you must in views drag and place the body field below them.

Also:

Make sure your format is Grid

[image]

Comment: But I want to achieve it only through template. (custom view tpl file).

Comment: **Just so you know the REWRITE method it's just as good as the .tpl method if you are only using html.** IMO the only time the .tpl method is worth doing is if you're gonna use PHP.

Comment: and what if I want to use html and php both, (say) foreach(view[field]) add html div with some class? That's the only reason, i'm chasing tpl method. Because we can not use php itself to generate output in views.